# How to attach event to dom created in link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know that dom created in template function can be attached to an event in controller.As:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('appClick', function(){
     return {
       restrict: 'A',
       scope: true,
       template: '<button ng-click="click()">Click me</button> Clicked {{clicked}} times',
       controller: function($scope, $element){
         $scope.clicked = 0;
         $scope.click = function(){
           $scope.clicked++
         }
       }
     }
   });
```

As there is no scope in template so I have to use link function.
The same how can I achieve in link function. Like:

```
 angular.module('app', [])
      .directive('appClick', function(){
         return {
           restrict: 'A',
           scope: true,
           link:function(scope, element, attrs){
  element.html('<button ng-click="click()">Click me</button> Clicked {{clicked}} times')
},
           controller: function($scope, $element){
             $scope.clicked = 0;
             $scope.click = function(){
               $scope.clicked++
             }
           }
         }
       });
```

How to attach event here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Angularjs` when you want to attach some `DOM` to the existing `DOM`. You first have to compile it with the `$compile` service on the `scope` for which you want to use the template. This is because template contain `Angular js` template syntax. Below is the working snippets.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
   $scope.message = 'Welcome message';
}])

myApp.directive('myTemplate', ['$compile',function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
    
      var el = $compile('<button ng-click="click()">Click me</button> Clicked {{clicked}} times')(scope);
      element.append(el);

      scope.clicked = 0;
      scope.click = function(){
         scope.clicked++
      }
    }
  }
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
    {{message}}
    <div my-template></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked! But 1 Q why       
element.append(el); and not element.html(el); (giving : [[object HTMLButtonElement], [object Text]])

Answer (score 0):

```
 angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('appClick', function(){
     return {
       restrict: 'A',
       scope: true,
       link:function(scope, element, attrs){

           element.html('<button ng-click="click()">Click me</button> Clicked {{clicked}} times')

             scope.clicked = 0;
             scope.click = function(){
               scope.clicked++
             }
         }
       });
```

Achieve this without controller.